# Why would admin-ajax.php redirect to the home page for logged out users?

Tags: ajax, poll

I am using the wp-polls plugin on my website. This plugin relies on using AJAX requests of the form http://www.myfakewebsiteurl.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=polls&view=process&poll_id=2&poll_2=8&poll_2_nonce=420d75e659

When I log in, this request works fine: it pulls the poll results from the server, and then displays them on the desired web page.

However, when I log out, this request redirects me to the home page. Thus, instead of the poll results appearing, I get the home page loaded where the poll results are supposed to be.

Why would admin-ajax.php redirect visitors to my Wordpress-powered site who are not logged in to the home page of my website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It only redirects when accessed directly, as do all files located in `wp-admin/`. AJAX requests should work fine regardless of authentication status.

**Edit:** `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` should *not* redirect in any situation. Perhaps a plugin is redirecting all unauthenticated users to the homepage? By default, accessing files inside wp-admin/ when not logged in should redirect to the login page.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not visiting the URL directly in my browser address bar. I'm retrieving the URL via AJAX in jQuery code. That should work, right?

Comment: Yes, it should. Perhaps a plugin is redirecting unauthenticated users to the homepage? By default, accessing files inside `wp-admin/` when not logged in should redirect to the login page.

Comment: OMG! You're right! I've been debugging this for 5 days, and I never suspected that! Apparently, one of my plugins was redirecting visitors if they were not logged in to the home page. I found this out by performing `grep -R 'redirect' .` in my `plugins` folder. I am still confused though. Why would code in another plugin be called? The AJAX request wasn't even relevant to this plugin ...

Comment: It depends on how the redirect is handled - if they check for the `WP_ADMIN` constant or use the `is_admin()` function, then it will trigger on any AJAX request or any wp-admin page

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. `admin-ajax.php` is an admin file.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so here's the deal. Redirect plugins have to do the following to avoid this issue.

```
if ( !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {}
```

It's that simple. Simple mistake, and easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and for me the reason wasn't broken plugin code. To find this one, I really needed to debug the wp_redirect code in `wp-includes/pluggable.php:1246` and add the following lines at the beginning of the function:

```
  var_dump($location);
  var_dump($status);
  var_dump(wp_debug_backtrace_summary());
  die;
```

Usually, you may inject such code via a filter like `wp_redirect` but that didn't work for me since the error occurred before my theme or plugin code was loaded by WordPress. Now, I observed the response body of my AJAX request in the developer network tools of my browser. You may also use `trigger_error(wp_debug_backtrace_summary())` and observe the stacktrace in `wp-content/debug.log` (if you enable the debug log).

My issue was naming a file in my theme `admin.php` and importing it with `include_once("admin.php");`. Strangely, the requirement logic starts looking for a file with that name in the upper parent folder,s and thus, it loada `wp-admin/admin.php` leading to an authentication error and finally my erroneous redirect.

And here goes the solution to my particular issue:

```
// Instead of: include_once('admin.php');
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . 'admin.php');
```

I guess, there are many ways to have such redirect issues. Hopefully, my problem-solving method helps other people out there with their problems.

Greetings,
Thomas